# Highcharts submits a date that is off by one day

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to make a click event on Highcharts and send it to a form, but the date that is submitted is always off by one day. I read that it might be solved by making the date UTC, I tried it, but didn't manage to get it working. Here is my JS code:

```js
<script>

      var chart1; // globally available
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        chart1 = Highcharts.stockChart('container', {

            chart: {
              events: {
                click: function(event) {
                  document.getElementById('date').value = Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d', event.xAxis[0].value);
                  document.forms[1].submit();
                }
              }
            },

            rangeSelector: {
                selected: 1
            },
            scrollbar: {
            barBackgroundColor: 'gray',
            barBorderRadius: 7,
            barBorderWidth: 0,
            buttonBackgroundColor: 'gray',
            buttonBorderWidth: 0,
            buttonBorderRadius: 7,
            trackBackgroundColor: 'none',
            trackBorderWidth: 1,
            trackBorderRadius: 0,
            trackBorderColor: '#CCC'
            },
            series: [{
                name: {{ticker | tojson}},
                data: {{ data|tojson }},
           }]
       });
    });
    </script>
```

Clarification: what I am trying to do is that when I click on the graph, the date on the graph is used as input for my date form and submitted [image: (see photo)]

Comment: Could you reproduce your case with the sample data which will show the issue? For now, it's hard to say more without seeing your data structure.

Comment: I don't know if this is what you mean but the data used by my chart looks like this [[1598313600000, 141], [1598400000000, 142]...] ([timestamp in milliseconds, stockprice]).

Comment: I have added a little bit more explanation @SebastianWędzel

Comment: `but the date that is submitted is always off by one day.` - are you able to reproduce this issue? I want to see the chart and the submitted data array. I am guessing that it might be related to the `dataGrouping` feature. https://www.highcharts.com/docs/stock/data-grouping